# If you roll three dice, what is the probability of getting at least two number are same?

Tags: probability

If you roll three dice,What is the probability of getting at least two numbers the same?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:  compute the chance they are all different, then subtract from $1$.